# Problems computing the DFT of finite length sequence

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, dft, fourier-series, math

I am having trouble finding the same answer as the solution manual for this sequence.

The problem asks to compute the DFT of
$$
x[n] = \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{for even } n \in \{0\ldots N-1\}
         \\ 0 & \text{for odd } n \in \{0\ldots N-1\}
       \end{cases}
$$

Setting up the DFT equation I agree with the solution manual
$$
  X[k]=\sum_0^{N-1}x[n]W^{kn}_{N}=\sum_0^{\frac{N}{2}-1}W^{k2n}_{N}=\sum_0^{\frac{N}{2}-1}e^{\frac{-j2\pi k(2n)}{N}}
$$

However when apply the closed form geometric series formula $\sum_0^Na^k=\frac{1-a^{N+1}}{1-a}$ I get
$$
\frac{1-e^{-j2\pi k}}{1-e^{\frac{-j2\pi k}{N}}}
$$

while the solution manual says its
$$\frac{1-e^{-j2\pi k}}{1-e^{\frac{-j\pi k}{N}}}$$

Note their lower exponent does not have a 2. Could someone explain where and how the 2 goes away?  Or does someone agree that the provided answer is incorrect?

This is question 8.5c from Oppenheim's Discrete-Time Signal Processing 3e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $N$ even :

$$
\begin{align}
X[k] &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] ~ W_N^{kn} ~~~,~~~k=0,1,...,N-1\\ \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N/2-1} 1 ~ W_N^{k ~2n}  \\ \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N/2-1} e^{-j 4\pi kn/N} \\ \\
& = \frac{ 1 - e^{-j \frac{4\pi k}{N}N/2 }}{ 1 - e^{-j 4\pi k/N}} \\ \\ 
& = \frac{ 1 - e^{-j 2\pi k}}{ 1 - e^{-j 4\pi k/N}}~~~,~~~k=0,1,...,N-1\\ 
\end{align}
$$

The result equals:
$$
X[k] = \begin{cases}{ ~~~ N/2 ~~~ ,~~~ k = 0, N/2 \\ ~~~~~~ 0 ~~~~~ ~ ,~ ~\text{otherwise} } \end{cases}
$$

Comment: glad you posted this, I wrote an answer up and was hesitant to post it seeing that my answer didn't match either of OP's hah.

Comment: @Fat32 thanks for the explanation.  I didn't realize either was not correct.  The relationship between the big N and little n keeps confusing me.  based on your steps 3-4 I can see the little n is based on the summation length while the big N is based on the overall sequence length.. am I correct with this assumption?  
Could you also explain how you got the result to equal $N/2$? Is there some formula or assumptions you are making?

Comment: @Fat32 I guess I may be misunderstanding something, for either one of them if k goes to $0$ or $N/2$ I see the exp going to either 1 (for $0$) or some other value (for $N/2$).

Comment: @Fat32  I am still unsure how you are getting the final result.  How does final value result in $N/2$ when it is based on the exponent? Is there some property of the exponential I am missing? For example - case $k=0$ i see it resulting in  $\frac{1-e^0}{1-e^0}=\frac{1-1}{1-1}=0$?  Maybe I am misunderstanding some concept about $e$?

Comment: @Fat32  so after thinking a bit more, I am assuming it is connected to the fact $e$ is representing a sinusoidal signal.  I will evaluate it using Euler’s equations and update.

Comment: @scott ok now. You can use the primary summation equation to evalaute the exponential fraction at the indices $k = 0$ and $k = N/2$ by noticing that the complex exonential $e^{-j4\pi k n / N}$ becomes $e^{-j4\pi 0 n / N} = 1$ and $e^{-j4\pi ( N/2) n / N} = 1$ which yield: $$X[0] =\sum_{n=0}^{N/2-1} 1 = N/2$$ and $$X[N/2] =\sum_{n=0}^{N/2-1} 1 = N/2$$ For other indices of $k$, notice that the numerator is already $0$, and denominator is nonzero; hence the result is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Figured I'd post this since I wrote it anyway, just a confirmation of Fat32's answer.

Letting $N' = \frac{N}{2} - 1$ we have
$\sum_{0}^{\frac{N}{2} - 1} e^{\frac{-j2\pi k (2n)}{N}}  = \sum_{0}^{N'} e^{\frac{-j2\pi k 
 n}{(N'+1)}}$

Then plugging in the geometric sum formula:

$=\frac{1 - e^{\frac{-j2\pi k(N'+1)}{(N'+1)}}}{1-e^{\frac{-j2\pi k}{(N'+1)}}}=\frac{1 - e^{\frac{-j2\pi k}{1}}}{1-e^{\frac{-j2\pi k}{(N'+1)}}}$

and finally reverting back to our original variable $N=2(N'+1)$ gives
$=\frac{1 - e^{\frac{-j2\pi k}{1}}}{1-e^{\frac{-j4\pi k}{N}}}$